# Can someone help me with MQTT in Python/IronPython to publish and subscribe a variable?

Tags: python, server, client, mqtt

I Want to send a variable with MQTT, but don't really know how this works.
can someone help me or has a final code for Client and Server?

Comment: What research have you done before asking this question? There are hundreds of examples under the python & mqtt tags here on Stack Overflow to get you started.

Answer (score 3):

Try paho-mqtt python client

Install it with:
pip install paho-mqtt

Project web page: https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#usage-and-api

Example:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe("$SYS/#")

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("mqtt.eclipse.org", 1883, 60)

# Blocking call that processes network traffic, dispatches callbacks and
# handles reconnecting.
# Other loop*() functions are available that give a threaded interface and a
# manual interface.
client.loop_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Paho-MQTT by pip install paho-mqtt
you can refer this link to get to know all about python mqtt [Beginner’s Guide To Using Paho-MQTT, A Python MQTT Client](https://mntolia.com/mqtt-python-with-paho-mqtt-client/)

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

#is called each time the client connects/reconnects to the broker. 
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("on_connect  ", client, userdata, flags, rc)


def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print("on_log ", client, userdata, level, buf)

#on_message is used to process messages that are published to a subscribed topic.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    topic = msg.topic
    m_decode = str(msg.payload.decode("UTF-8"))
    print("on_message ", topic, m_decode)

#The on_disconnect() callback is called when the client disconnects from the broker.
def on_disconnect(client, userdata, flags, rc=0):
    print("on_disconnect ", client, userdata, flags, rc)


broker = "broker.hivemq.com"

client = mqtt.Client("client_id")

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_log = on_log
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect

print("connecting to broker ", broker)
client.connect(broker) # connecting to the broker
# subscribing to the topics.
client.subscribe("my_topic/1")
client.subscribe("my_topic/2")
#publishing on to the topics 
client.publish("my_topic/1", "my_message_1")
client.publish("my_topic/2", "my_message_2")

#The loop functions are made to process any messages in the buffer and call a respective callback function.
client.loop_start()

time.sleep(4)
client.loop_stop()
client.disconnect()
```

Comment: This is a link only answer that will become totally useless as soon as the link breaks

Comment: okay thanks for advising i have added code for better understanding.@hardillb

Comment: paho doesn't work, are there any other libraries?

Comment: what language and ide are you using ? can i see your code and installed libraries?

Comment: paho does work, I'm using it in multiple projects with no problems. Check your connection settings in client.connect(), and try to publish and subscribe to your server with mosquitto_pub/sub client first to ensure server is configured correctly.